# Rename [poisson] in [poisson-distribution]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-renaming

I suggest to rename [poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson) into [poisson-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson-distribution), given that its wiki excerpt says

> A discrete distribution defined on the non-negative integers that has the property that the mean is equal to the variance.

**and** given that we have [poisson-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson-regression), [poisson-process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson-process), and [poisson-binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson-binomial) tags.

Comment: This seems like a no-brainer. If there's no dissent after a period of time, ping me & I'll do it.

Comment: I'd say this can go forward @gung.

Comment: It's done now, @amoeba.

Comment: Thanks @gung. I am a bit concerned that [poisson] is now a synonym of [poisson-distribution]. Wouldn't it make more sense to delete this synonym?

Comment: Do you want `[poisson]` to simply not exist? It's been merged w/ p-d.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. I am not sure it makes sense to map any tag [a] to [a-b] when we also have [a-c], [a-d], etc. It's like with [fisher] when we got rid of this tag entirely. AFAIK there is no mod tool to just *rename* a tag, so the only way to rename is to create a synonym, merge, and then delete the synonym mapping. That said, if you have an argument for why [poisson] should stay as a synonym, then I am fine with it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I deleted the synonym mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a no-brainer.  I created the tag (i.e., [poisson-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poisson-distribution)), made them synonyms, merged them (so that all threads that used to have `[poisson]` now have `[poisson-distribution]` instead, without bumping >1k threads to the main page), and deleted the old `[poisson]` tag.